# Why I can not get Terminator to use the default defined shell?

Tags: shell, fedora, zsh, oh-my-zsh, gnome-terminator

I am using ZSH as my default shell and OhMyZsh as well as the following command shows:

```
❯ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
```

I have been following what it is found at https://askubuntu.com/a/253819 but with no luck meaning Terminator is not using the default shell. Each time I open Terminator I see something like:

```
bash: register-python-argcomplete: command not found
bash: /usr/libexec/grepconf.sh: No such file or directory
bash: /usr/libexec/grepconf.sh: No such file or directory
bash: /bin/basename: No such file or directory
bash: /usr/libexec/vte-urlencode-cwd: No such file or directory
[reypm@localhos]$
```

If I do the following Terminator won't start:

[image]

What I am missing here? I am running Fedora 32

Comment: It might be yet another problem with the VTE hack in `/etc/profile.d/vte.sh`

Comment: @ThomasDickey what is this VTE hack and how is not allowing me to run ZSH as default shell in Terminator? Sorry for my ignorance but I am not following you

Comment: Read the script: someone is making a check against a particular version of VTE which Terminator may/may not be using.  An earlier version of the script generated a syntax error; this one is (a little) improved, but guaranteed to work only with gnome-terminal.

Comment: @ThomasDickey well I am reading the script but don't understand what is trying to do neither know how to fix my problem

Comment: I'd ask myself what the variables are in my shell, such as `$VTE_VERSION`, and turn on the shell trace to see what it does with that.